# How to override checkout_index_index.xml

Tags: magento2, xml, page-layouts, extend, magento-checkout

this is the file present in my app/design dir. i need to  disply  shipping address section on right side bar and move the product overview section from right side bar to the place of currenct shipping address section. i am beginner can somebody please guide me how to do that?
[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
        <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">75</item>
            <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                <item name="validate-zip-us" xsi:type="string">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 2 way to archive this.

1. Override this file into your `custom extension` like

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

1. Directly you can modify code into your theme file like `app\design`.

`checkout_index_index.xml` file code is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="shipping-information" destination="checkout.cart.container" after="checkout.cart.totals"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                                 
                                                  <!-- show shipping info at the top of sidebar -->
                                                <item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information</item>
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shipping-information</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="ship-to" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ship-to</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>  
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                              <!-- disable shipping information section from siderbar -->
                                        <item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: hi Dhiren i dont understand how the move element is not working here
can you give me lne code which can move the prodcut summary to where adress is and adress to sidebar

Comment: @Harris I update answer with code, kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create or Locate checkout_index_index.xml in Your Theme:

If it already exists in your theme, great. If not, you can create it in your theme's layout directory. For example, if your theme is named Vendor/Theme, the file path would be:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

2. Update the XML File:

Place the following code in your checkout_index_index.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <!-- Move the shipping address to the right sidebar -->
    <move element="checkout.shipping.address" destination="sidebar.additional" after="-"/>

    <!-- Move the product overview to the main content area -->
    <move element="checkout.cart.container" destination="content" before="-"/>
   </body>
  </page>
```

3. Clear Cache:

   php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but that didint work for some reason can you please guide me how can i move it?

Comment: i have posted a pic in the post for better understanding